# Chromium extreme compilation time difference when using a custom clang binary

Tags: c++, compilation, clang, chromium

I compiled chromium's `base_unittests` benchmark using the clang binary shipped with the project and the compilation took only a few minutes. But when I use a custom clang binary, by setting `args.gn` as instructed [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/clang.md#Using-a-custom-clang-binary), although the benchmark compiles fine but the compilation takes about an hour. What is the reason behind this extreme compilation time difference?

I am on a local x86_64 machine running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and both clang binaries are of version 16.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

When you change a build toolchain, it rebuilds the entire project with all dependencies. If you return to the previously used toolchain, it will rebuild the entire project with all dependencies again and not in a few minutes.